# How to wrap two unmanaged C++ functions into two managed C# functions?

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, managed, dllexport

I've got two unmanaged C++ functions, `Compress` and `Decompress`. The arguments and returns go as followed:

unsigned char* `Compress` (unsigned char*,int)

unsigned char* `Decompress` (unsigned char*,int)

Where all uchars are arrays of uchars.

Could someone please help me lay out a way to convert these into managed C# code using the Byte[] array instead of unsigned char*? Thank you very much!

Comment: Not clear: do you want to a) reinvent the functions, b) write wrappers for them in Managed C++, or c) compile them into an unmanaged DLL and call them from .NET using P/Invoke?

Comment: Managed and unmanaged are redundant on the question title.

What you have is two C++ functions that you need to wrap into C#

Comment: I would like to call them from .NET using P/Invoke, I'm sorry for not clarifying well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass the unsigned char* parameter in as a byte[] and standard P/Invoke marshaller should handle that.  You will have to marshal the output unsigned char* yourself, but that should just be a call to Marshall.Copy().  See below for an example of what I think will work.

Two big questions:

1. How does the caller know the size of data stored in the return unsigned char* buffer?
2. How is the memory allocated for the return unsigned char* buffer?  Do you have to free it and how will you free it from C# if you need to?

Sample:

```
    [DllImport("Name.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr Compress([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]byte[] buffer, int size);

    [DllImport("Name.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr Decompress([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]byte[] buffer, int size);

    public static byte[] Compress(byte[] buffer) {
        IntPtr output = Compress(buffer, buffer.Length);
        /* Does output need to be freed? */
        byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[/*some size?*/];
        Marshal.Copy(output, outputBuffer, 0, outputBuffer.Length);
        return outputBuffer;
    }

    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] buffer) {
        IntPtr output = Decompress(buffer, buffer.Length);
        /* Does output need to be freed? */
        byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[/*some size?*/];
        Marshal.Copy(output, outputBuffer, 0, outputBuffer.Length);
        return outputBuffer;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That should work fine for now, I've got some functions that can get the size of decompressed output as well as compressed output. My only other question is how I'm going to free the output in C#.